# Seek helps to speed up my mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

Edited for detail of my case.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fbuid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fbuid` (`fbuid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (`id`, `fbuid`, `fullname`) VALUES
(1, 1002, 'User B'),
(2, 1001, 'User A'),
(3, 1003, 'User C'),
(4, 1004, 'User D'),
(5, 1005, 'User E'),
(6, 1006, 'User F');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_userscores` (
  `fbuid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `game_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `score1` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `score2` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `score3` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `score4` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`game_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fbuid` (`fbuid`,`game_id`),
  KEY `fbuid_2` (`fbuid`,`game_id`,`score4`),
  KEY `fbuid_3` (`fbuid`,`game_id`,`score4`,`updated_date`),
  KEY `fbuid_4` (`fbuid`,`game_id`,`score1`,`score2`,`score3`,`score4`,`created_date`,`updated_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_userscores` (`fbuid`, `game_id`, `score1`, `score2`, `score3`, `score4`, `created_date`, `updated_date`) VALUES
(1001, '13361975565253060', 650, 3300, 7675, 14500, '2012-05-05 13:59:55', '2012-05-05 14:01:50'),
(1001, '1336278398787510', 3100, 87725, 326675, 573625, '2012-05-06 12:28:20', '2012-05-06 12:33:27'),
(1001, '13368015862343980', 12875, 82550, 158625, 299550, '2012-05-12 13:48:08', '2012-05-12 13:53:15'),
(1001, '13369691453105020', 7925, 58525, 283100, 368225, '2012-05-14 12:20:47', '2012-05-14 12:25:54'),
(1002, '1336328839124400', 1275, 11475, 31450, 50475, '2012-05-07 02:27:34', '2012-05-07 02:28:20'),
(1002, '13363686059958120', 11025, 48900, 72725, 115150, '2012-05-07 13:30:21', '2012-05-07 13:31:07'),
(1002, '13364088902032830', 6650, 6700, 10200, 17625, '2012-05-08 00:41:46', '2012-05-08 00:42:32'),
(1002, '13364910479425300', 3600, 17050, 60450, 114800, '2012-05-08 23:31:03', '2012-05-08 23:31:49'),
(1002, '13364949763272710', 17250, 168125, 479475, 596925, '2012-05-07 00:37:33', '2012-05-07 00:41:21'),
(1003, '13363240964199380', 84150, 84150, 84150, 84150, '2012-05-07 01:11:37', '2012-05-07 01:12:22'),
(1003, '1336465518338010', 297275, 351300, 437150, 468350, '2012-05-08 16:31:52', '2012-05-08 16:32:38'),
(1003, '13368122913207860', 0, 82350, 94150, 102750, '2012-05-12 16:45:20', '2012-05-12 16:48:09'),
(1003, '13368125091164060', 423925, 428125, 521875, 589750, '2012-05-12 16:54:00', '2012-05-12 16:54:47'),
(1004, '13363118226930570', 3275, 10975, 16250, 22900, '2012-05-06 21:43:58', '2012-05-06 21:44:43'),
(1004, '13366228756934380', 23275, 149100, 380600, 382075, '2012-05-10 12:08:46', '2012-05-10 12:10:49'),
(1004, '13366232802957960', 3650, 23525, 49975, 49975, '2012-05-10 12:14:55', '2012-05-10 12:15:42'),
(1005, '13361215491096720', 1200, 16250, 39125, 55800, '2012-05-04 16:52:59', '2012-05-04 16:54:29'),
(1005, '13361216729657120', 11000, 29800, 82575, 188550, '2012-05-04 16:55:03', '2012-05-04 16:56:33'),
(1005, '13361364491988250', 6925, 50925, 89100, 180425, '2012-05-04 21:01:12', '2012-05-04 21:02:43'),
(1005, '13362204979150640', 11300, 39800, 63675, 78725, '2012-05-05 20:22:08', '2012-05-05 20:23:36'),
(1005, '13362311869003160', 11575, 61500, 134200, 233600, '2012-05-05 23:20:17', '2012-05-05 23:21:48'),
(1005, '133628163373910', 3500, 40175, 131375, 251725, '2012-05-06 13:21:03', '2012-05-06 13:22:35'),
(1006, '13361224889844730', 6700, 30575, 49650, 50475, '2012-05-04 17:08:24', '2012-05-04 17:09:10'),
(1006, '13366294182421110', 16800, 87675, 119150, 206500, '2012-05-10 13:57:42', '2012-05-10 14:00:15'),
(1006, '13366296357158010', 23050, 99025, 229075, 381925, '2012-05-10 14:01:27', '2012-05-10 14:03:58'),
(1006, '13368319289949330', 22975, 130375, 350600, 355150, '2012-05-12 22:13:00', '2012-05-12 22:15:08');
```

With above data, I use sql below to get weekly highscore.

```
SELECT U1.fbuid, U1.fullname, U2.score4 AS weeklyhighscore, U2.created_date, U2.updated_date, TIMEDIFF( U2.updated_date, U2.created_date ) AS Duration
    FROM tbl_user AS U1, (  
                SELECT fbuid, score4, MIN( updated_date ) AS updated_date, created_date
                FROM tbl_userscores AS A
                WHERE A.score4
                IN (
                    SELECT MAX(  `score4` ) AS best
                    FROM tbl_userscores AS B
                    WHERE A.fbuid = B.fbuid
                    AND B.score1 >0
                    AND B.score2 >0
                    AND B.score3 >0
                    AND B.score4 >0
                    AND `updated_date` >= '2012-05-06 00:00:00' AND `updated_date` <= '2012-05-12 23:59:59'
                    GROUP BY fbuid
                )
                GROUP BY A.fbuid
                ORDER BY  `A`.`score4` DESC , updated_date ASC
            ) AS U2
WHERE U1.fbuid = U2.fbuid
ORDER BY weeklyhighscore DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Expected result :

```
+-------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| fbuid | fullname | weeklyhighscore | created_date        | updated_date        | Duration |
| 1002  | User B   | 596925          | 2012-05-07 00:37:33 | 2012-05-07 00:41:21 | 00:03:48 |
| 1003  | User C   | 589750          | 2012-05-12 16:54:00 | 2012-05-12 16:54:47 | 00:00:47 |
| 1001  | User A   | 573625          | 2012-05-06 12:28:20 | 2012-05-06 12:33:27 | 00:05:07 |
| 1004  | User D   | 382075          | 2012-05-10 12:08:46 | 2012-05-10 12:10:49 | 00:02:03 |
| 1006  | User F   | 381925          | 2012-05-10 14:01:27 | 2012-05-10 14:03:58 | 00:02:31 |
| 1005  | User E   | 251725          | 2012-05-06 13:21:03 | 2012-05-06 13:22:35 | 00:01:32 |
+-------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I have two table, tbl_user and tbl_userscores. Each time user played a game, it will save times as score1 to score4 (4 session of scores, which score4 is final score).

tbl_userscores was indexed with (fbuid,score4,updated_date,create_date). It have 45K records, and keep growing.

I want to get top 30 weekly highscorer. This query took me average 45sec to complete.

So I would like to seek expert's advice on how to make it much better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: General rule of thumb: any field used in a JOIN or a WHERE clause should have an index on it.

Comment: Thanks Marc, i indexed score1,score2 and score3 together and now the query took 18.7836 sec. Any rooms for improvement still?

Comment: @MFei you should try this query ....

Comment: @QueryMaster, I am using same sql like yours before. This query returned correct highest score of fbuid but wrong create and updated date. The date returned was always the last row's date of the inner query. :(

Comment: @MFei if you don't mind can you share me screenshot result what exactly you want

Comment: @QueryMaster, how to share to you? Here?

Comment: @MFei you want to add more stuff in your question like *result screen* then edit your Question and reply me

Comment: @MFei check my update answer below

Comment: @QueryMaster Sorry I didnt find your query anymore. BTW, Nikola's query works well with inner join. Thanks for your helps and time ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that most of the time is spent in correlated subquery that extracts max(score4) per user. It might be restructured to get top 30 scores at once and used as a filter to main table. Unfortunately, as you might get duplicates and need to take earliest updated_date to avoid them, there is additional derived table to get this filter. If this proves to be the slowest part, you might remove `minUpdated` derived table, envelop complete query and use `not exists` to select records with minimal updated_date per score4 only. This should be faster as you will tipically have just a bit over 30 records.

```
SELECT U1.fbuid, 
       U1.fullname, 
       U2.score4 AS weeklyhighscore, 
       U2.created_date, 
       U2.updated_date, 
       TIMEDIFF( U2.updated_date, U2.created_date ) AS Duration
FROM tbl_user AS U1
INNER JOIN tbl_userscores U2
   ON U1.FbUid = U2.FbUid
/* Top 30 scores by user */
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT B.fbuid, 
         MAX(`score4`) AS best
    FROM tbl_userscores AS B
   WHERE B.score1 > 0
     AND B.score2 > 0
     AND B.score3 > 0
     AND B.score4 > 0
     AND `updated_date` >= '2012-05-06 00:00:00'
     AND `updated_date` < '2012-05-13 00:00:00'
   GROUP BY fbuid
   ORDER BY best DESC
   LIMIT 30
) A
   ON U2.FbUid = A.FbUid
  AND U2.Score4 = best
/* Filter by min(updated_date) in case of several same scores per user */
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT FbUid, Score4, MIN(updated_date) updated_date
    FROM tbl_userscores
   GROUP BY FbUid, Score4
) minUpdated
   ON U2.FbUid = minUpdated.FbUid
  AND U2.Score4 = minUpdated.Score4
  AND U2.Updated_date = minUpdated.Updated_date
ORDER BY weeklyhighscore DESC
```

I've replaced date comparison with more promising pattern >= and <. This change avoids the datetime resolution issues (you might loose a record if an update is made in last 999 milliseconds of a day). This is also great defence tool - your query will work even if somebody somehow manages to input time portion of a date where your business logic does not expect one.

Comment: Thanks Nikola for reply. Tested yours but return wrong weekly highscore and user also. :(

Comment: Sorry Nikola, after I create a temp db with above data which I edited. It shows correct info. But when I used your query on live data. It was wrong one. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, I found whats wrong with yours. Need DESC for "ORDER BY best" in second inner join in order to get highscores.

Comment: @MFei Silly me, sorry for this mistake. I'm curious about performance - would you please tell me how it went? Also without `minUpdated` derived table?

Comment: Ya, thanks for your helps.

With minUpdated
Showing rows 0 - 29 (30 total, Query took 0.3855 sec)

Without minUpdated 
Showing rows 0 - 29 (30 total, Query took 0.1043 sec)

Now the query was from 11secs average down to less then 1sec. bravo.